# How can I use German umlauts in DeclareMathOperator?

Tags: math-operators

I would like to define a math operator `Homöo`, but when I try

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\Homoo}{Homöo}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Homoo}{Hom\"oo}
```

I get `Homo`.

**How can I use German umlauts in DeclareMathOperator?**

(If it's not possible at all: What should I do instead?)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The text in the second argument of `\DeclareMathOperator` is typeset in a special variety of `\mathrm`, so `-` produce a hyphen, for instance, not a minus sign. Fragments of words like yours can be dealt with by saying

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\Homoo}{\textnormal{Homöo}}
```

assuming a non fancy setup for fonts.

Comment: @moose Moreover, you should use `\textnormal` if you need kerning in the operator. I recently needed it for the variance to get correct kerning between `V` and `a`: `\DeclareMathOperator{\Var}{\textnormal{Var}}`.

Comment: @Manuel: Thank you for the hint. When do I not need kerning in the operator? (For everybody who has to look up kerning: [Wiki-article about kerning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerning), [one example](http://nitens.org/taraborelli/latex#kerning))

Comment: @moose I just wrote an example, if you use `\DeclareMathOperator{\Var}{Var}` and compare it with the one I used, you will see the difference, the `V` letter has space under it to put the lowercase `a`. There is no general rule for kerning, you need it when two letters can be kerned.

Comment: @Manuel, I was asking the other way around: Is there any reason **not** to use `\textnormal`?

Comment: @Manuel I get *no* difference between `\operatorname{Var}` and `\operatorname{\textnormal{Var}}`

Comment: @moose I don't know (may be that *special variety of \mathrm* which egreg mentioned invites you NOT to use `\textnormal`). Egreg, my fault, it's just a problem in XeLaTeX **with `fontspec`**. I will delete my comments.

Comment: @moose There is no reason for using `\textnormal` in general.

Comment: @egreg Now, I think it could be a bug. Because in the usual `\mathrm` (for instance) you get proper kerning and ligatures BUT after loading `fontspec` it doesn't work “correctly”.

Comment: @Manuel Yes, it's a problem with `fontspec`; kerning is not applied. I think it's something that should be fixed, but it surely requires interaction with `amsmath`.